# Android + Retrofit 2 + GSON = Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2, gson

I'm trying to use retrofit 2 in my app and i'm getting the folloing error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface box.gov.br.ourapp.API.ClientePFApi. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.`

And... I dunno where's the problem =/

My java class:

```java
public class ClientePFVisao360 {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 3182722297876508581L;

@SerializedName("txCPF")
@Expose
public String txCPF;

@SerializedName("nuCocli")
@Expose
public Long nuCocli;

@SerializedName("txNomeCliente")
@Expose
public String txNomeCliente;

@SerializedName("dtNascimento")
@Expose
public String dtNascimento;

@SerializedName("dtInicioRelacionamento")
@Expose
public String dtInicioRelacionamento;

@SerializedName("txSegmento")
@Expose
public String txSegmento;

@SerializedName("txOcupacao")
@Expose
public String txOcupacao;

@SerializedName("txSexo")
@Expose
public String txSexo;

@SerializedName("txEstadoCivil")
@Expose
public String txEstadoCivil;

@SerializedName("txNivelInstrucao")
@Expose
public String txNivelInstrucao;

@SerializedName("txTipoPessoa")
@Expose
public String txTipoPessoa;

@SerializedName("nuNacionalidade")
@Expose
public Integer nuNacionalidade;

@SerializedName("txNaturalidade")
@Expose
public String txNaturalidade;

@SerializedName("txNomePai")
@Expose
public String txNomePai;

@SerializedName("txNomeMae")
@Expose
public String txNomeMae;

@SerializedName("txDeficiencia")
@Expose
public String txDeficiencia;

@SerializedName("nichos")
@Expose
public List<String> nichos;

@SerializedName("conjuge")
@Expose
public Conjuge conjuge;

@SerializedName("renda")
@Expose
public Renda renda;

@SerializedName("meiosComunicacao")
@Expose
public MeioComunicacao meiosComunicacao;

@SerializedName("carteiraGRC")
@Expose
public List<CarteiraGrc> carteiraGRC;

//getters and setters....

public ClientePFVisao360() {
}
```

My Interface:

```java
public interface ClientePFApi {
    @GET("clientepf/{user}")
    Call<ClientePFApi> getClientePF(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

How I'm calling this:

```java
    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient();
    Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API)
            .client(okClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    ClientePFApi service = client.create(ClientePFApi.class);
    Call<ClientePFApi> call = service.getClientePF("bigua");

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ClientePFApi>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ClientePFApi> call, @NonNull Response<ClientePFApi> response) {
            Log.e("retrofit", "ok");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ClientePFApi> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Log.e("trow", t.toString());
            Log.e("retrofit", "crash");
        }
    });
```

The JSON i'm received from my API:

> {"txCPF":"1234567","nuCocli":12345,"txNomeCliente":"bla","dtNascimento":"12/11/1984","dtInicioRelacionamento":"04/05/2010","txSegmento":"bla","txOcupacao":"bla","txSexo":"bla","txEstadoCivil":"bla","txNivelInstrucao":"bla","txTipoPessoa":"bla","nuNacionalidade":null,"txNaturalidade":"DF","txNomePai":"blah","txNomeMae":"bla","txDeficiencia":null,"nichos":null,"conjuge":null,"renda":null,"meiosComunicacao":null,"carteiraGRC":null}

I'm sorry if its a noob problem/question, but i've read many questions here and don't get where is my mistake.

thanks in advice for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is a problem because you user same name for `interface` class and your `Model` class.

both are same name here `ClientePFApi` .

```
public interface ClientePFApi {
    @GET("clientepf/{user}")
    Call<ClientePFApi> getClientePF(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

you use `ClientePFVisao360` like below

```
public interface ClientePFApi {
        @GET("clientepf/{user}")
        Call<ClientePFVisao360> getClientePF(@Path("user") String user);
    }
```

Comment: Oh... I see... , changed and the error changed too, but it seems that the JSON its bad formated , new error: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 499 path $.nichos

Comment: This errors because in your `ClientePFVisao360` class `nichos` and `carteiraGRC` is List object and in your `Json` contains `null` for that key. To resolve this you need to blank array `[]` in place of `null` for that key.

Answer (score 1):

if for example your api service method is this

```
interface ExampleInterface {
     @POST("sample")
     suspend  fun sampleFun(): Call<JsonObject>
}
```

change it to this

```
interface ExampleInterface {
     @POST("sample")
     fun sampleFun(): Call<JsonObject>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to Change `<Call>` to `<Response>`