# Retrofit 2.0 + GSON + Android: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface retrofit2.http.Body

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

I am trying to create a simple News app with the following endpoint:

https://content.guardianapis.com/search?api-key=...&show-fields=thumbnail&show-blocks=body&type=article

I know there are 2-3 questions already on SO about this but I belive that this exception is unique since it can not create a constructor for a **library interace?!...**

Here are my project files:

[Retrofit client](https://github.com/rolandsarosy/The-Guardian-API/blob/master/app/src/main/java/cloud/augmentum/theguardianapi/api/service/NewsClient.java)

[Model classes](https://github.com/rolandsarosy/The-Guardian-API/tree/master/app/src/main/java/cloud/augmentum/theguardianapi/api/model)

[Custom adapter and activity](http://Custom%20adapter%20and%20activity)

I get the following RuntimeException when trying to call

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<News>() {
```

In the main activity:

```
Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface retrofit2.http.Body. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

So far I have tried:

- Creating no-arg constructors for each of my model classes as mentioned in another similar question
- Checking whether the any of the classes share similar names with the retrofit interace as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33749752/retrofit-2-0-gson-unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-interface) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114774/android-retrofit-2-gson-unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-interface?rq=1)

Any idea what could cause this? I belive my code should be working and since the error is with a the `retrofit2.http.Body` interface which to my knowledge I should not have to implement anywhere...

I really appreciate any form of help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Blocks` model you have doesn't [import](https://github.com/rolandsarosy/The-Guardian-API/blob/5aa9df147abbc20ce2466e0edf322043de99f915/app/src/main/java/cloud/augmentum/theguardianapi/api/model/Blocks.java#L8) the correct `Body` type.

All you have to do is remove the following line:

```
import retrofit2.http.Body;
```

This way your model will use the `Body` class from the same package.

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed it and the API call works flawessly! May I ask, as someone who spent hours trying to figure this out: What led you to find this solution? I genuinely want to get better at this :P

Comment: @Augmentum the Gson library is responsible for deserializing JSON into Java classes. In order to do it, it instantiates the necessary classes (models) using the no-args constructor and then using reflection it writes the correct values into fields. Now, the "Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface retrofit2.http.Body" error is from Gson and it tells us that one of the models is or contains a field of this type.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the detailed explanation, it makes much more sense now :)